# Rotating ellipse around itself, treadmill

Tags: c#, rotation

So i'm trying to make some sort of treadmill or assambly line in unity3d.

I have no idea where to start with this, I tried a tank asset in the unity store and see how they moved the tracks but turned out they only moved the material around the tracks so no real physics in there.

Can anyone explain me how to start or how to program it in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X = x + (a * Math.cos(alpha))
Y = y + (b * Math.sin(alpha))
Where x,y are the coordinates of the center, and a,b are the axes, and alpha is the angle

Then:

```
gameObject.transform.position = Vector3(X,0,Y);
```

[x,y and a,b description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTOnE.png)